# 2nd derivative of f(x(t) , y(t))

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

So the first derivative w.r.t. t:

$\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \times \frac{dx}{dt} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial f} \times \frac{dy}{dt}$

How would I find the 2nd derivative?

EDIT:

In particular there is a term in when calculating the 2nd derivative :

$$ \frac {d}{dt} ( \frac {\partial f}{\partial x}) $$

It is calculating this step that  I do not understand

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What do you get when you differentiate both sides of the equation you already write for the first derivative?

Comment: I get completely lost in all the notation. I can see that you need to use the product rule, but how for example, does $ \frac{d}{dt} ( \frac {\partial f}{\partial x})$ go?

Comment: @orion yes the solution can be found here, I have updated my question to include specifically what I need help understanding. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just imagine we write $\frac{\partial f(x(t),y(t))}{\partial x}=g(x(t),y(t))$ to simplify notation. You differentiate it exactly as you did before, just for a different function:

$$\frac{dg}{dt}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

Now just realize that $g$ is already a derivative, so you get second derivatives:
$$\frac{dg}{dt}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

This step is used for parenthesised expressions between second and third line of [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2905613/iterating-total-derivative-how-to).